# mysql_connect() not working on MAC Xamp. It says missing file

Tags: php, mysql, macos

I am trying to connect a MYSQL database in php using XAMP. The code works in Windows but not working in MAC. There is no error coming but just blank screen. Anyone using MAC can help me on this? I think it needs some change in php.ini file, I removed the ; from the extensions for mysql.dll file but did not work.

My Db Connectivity Code is

```
<?php    
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
echo $con."<br />";
mysql_select_db('cfcdb', $con);
echo mysql_error($con);
?>
```

it does not print the $con and shows nothing.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]

Comment: RESOLVED. The xamp in mac does not have MYSQL but MYSQLi. So only mysqli functions are working.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED. The xamp in mac does not have MYSQL but MYSQLi. So only mysqli functions are working.